# Como manter e exibir a CountDown ao sair do app?

Tags: android, timer, sharedpreferences, countdown

Estou construindo um aplicativo para executar tarefas a cada hora, e eu quero mostrar contagem regressiva. Mas quando eu saio do aplicativo, ao voltar, a contagem reinicia. Preciso que ao voltar para o app, a contagem esteja continuando.
Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: para isso, voce vai precisar criar um serviço para rodar em background e setar esse serviço como de boot

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho  poderia postar um exemplo?

Comment: outra alternativa seria salvar no banco de dados a hora que o serviço vai levar para ser completado e a hora que a pessoa saiu do app, recomendo ler sobre [Ciclo de Vida de uma Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=pt-br#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks) e depois quando o user abrisse o app, ele calculava a diferença de horas (saída e entrada) e atualizava as horas restantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, vamos lá então:

primeiro, voce precisa inicializar o Serviço:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class ServicoIniciadoNoBoot extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Algo para ser feito quando o serviço for criado
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        // algo que precisa ser feito quando o serviço for incializado
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Algo que precisa ser feito quando o serviço for finalizado (destruido)
    }
}
```

Depois, voce vai precisar de um BroadcastReceiver, nele é que existe o método onReceive que será chamado na conclusão do evento de inicialização.
Nele, vamos lançar o Serviço que acabamos de criar.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootCompletadoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ServicoIniciadoNoBoot.class);
         context.startService(serviceIntent);
     }
}
```

Depois, voce precisa modificar o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml para que o app responda ao serviço:

1) adicione a permissão para capturar o evento do carregamento no boot do aparelho:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2) registre o Serviço:

```
<service android:name=".ServicoIniciadoNoBoot" ></service>
```

3) registre o BroadcastReceiver para receber o evento:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BootCompletadoReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Com esses passos voce cria um serviço rodando na sua app onde todas as vezes que for iniciado pela app ele continua rodando até o aparelho completar o booot, ou seja, for desligado.

Voce ficou a dever do que que voce tem feito ai em codigo, assim só deu pra ser generico, mas acredito que no onStart e no onCreate do Servico voce possa manipular o teu relógio.

Espero que ajude!